# How to determine the object property name dynamically

Tags: c#

I have an object User:

```
 public class User
    {

        public String Name { get; set; }


        public String Name2 { get; set; }


        public String Name3 { get; set; }


    }
```

Also I have a Key Value set of strings that I want to assign to the object's properties when I create it:

```
'Name':'srgrgsdfsdf'
'Name3':'dsfdsfafafd'
'Name2':'dtewtwerwer'
'Name4':'546353452552'
```

Now I create my object like this

```
  User user = new User();

  user.Name = "zzxasdas";
```

The problem is that I want to be able to assign the Key/Value data dynamically. This means that some of the items can be missing or the order may be different.

How can I check the name of the object properties dynamically and compare it with the Key like this:?

```
foreach [key] in Key/Value 
if [user] has property named [key] 
add [value] to [user] property with the name [key]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do this.

In particular, [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties) or [`Type.GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty.aspx) will allow you to discover information about the properties defined on a type, and get or set their values.

This might look something like:

```
User user = new User();

Type t = user.GetType();
foreach(var kvp in propertyDictionary)
{
    var prop = t.GetProperty(kvp.Key);
    if (prop != null)
       prop.SetValue(user, kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that comes to my mind.

One is obviously using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) APIs. For example, if user.GetType().GetProperty() etc.

Second, there might be a chance that [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is a solution for you which copies property from one object to another with same name